# Intellij Idea 9 slow response on typing

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ Idea 9 on a windows 7 box - 2GB RAM. I'm facing this strange issue where the response of the editor is very slow. When typing, the characters seem to appear after a delay.. and gets annoying after a point.

However, IDEA 8 on the same machine works perfectly.

Would like to know if someone has faced this earlier.. Or is there any recommended solution..

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized and just complaining about having a machine without enough RAM.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the 9.0.1 RC build available at http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/IDEADEV/Maia+EAP, some performance problems were resolved there. Also ensure you don't have third-party plug-ins installed.

If the issue remains, refer to the instructions at http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-192.

**EDIT**: IDEA 9.0.1 has been released, please use the latest available release build.

Comment: I'm using the latest version (9.0.3) and have tried some of the solutions to no avail, but will report back when I have tried more.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, in my case the issue was having the Project and Structure windows open, and having scroll to/from source enabled probably didn't help. Closing the palettes sped up editing for me.